# Ruby gem failure on installing ri documentation

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am trying to install GitLabHQ on my Debian 6.0.4 machine. It is a fresh install of April 13th, 2012. Now I have come to the point where I need some installs to be done by Ruby gem. In particular:

```
gem install bundler
```

This reveals the following error:

```
Successfully installed bundler-1.1.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.1.3...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
undefined class/module Encoding
```

Then I tried to rebuild the Ruby packages with

```
gem pristine --all
```

This did not help. Here is list of the Ruby packages installed:

```
rake-0.9.2.2 at Sat Apr 14 20:44:40 2012
rvm-1.11.3.3 at Sat Apr 14 20:44:47 2012
rubygems-bundler-0.9.0 at Mon Apr 16 09:04:32 2012
rack-test-0.6.1 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:10 2012
daemon_controller-1.0.0 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:10 2012
tilt-1.3.3 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:10 2012
erubis-2.7.0 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:10 2012
multi_json-1.2.0 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:10 2012
rack-cache-1.2 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:10 2012
thor-0.14.6 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:10 2012
actionmailer-3.2.3 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:10 2012
treetop-1.4.10 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:11 2012
fastthread-1.0.7 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:11 2012
activeresource-3.2.3 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:11 2012
polyglot-0.3.3 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:11 2012
i18n-0.6.0 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:12 2012
journey-1.0.3 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:12 2012
actionpack-3.2.3 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:12 2012
rack-ssl-1.3.2 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:12 2012
activesupport-3.2.3 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:12 2012
passenger-3.0.12 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:12 2012
railties-3.2.3 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:13 2012
rack-1.4.1 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:13 2012
sprockets-2.1.2 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:13 2012
mime-types-1.18 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:13 2012
arel-3.0.2 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:13 2012
hike-1.2.1 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:14 2012
mail-2.4.4 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:15 2012
activerecord-3.2.3 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:15 2012
activemodel-3.2.3 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:15 2012
tzinfo-0.3.33 at Mon Apr 16 09:11:15 2012
builder-3.0.0 at Mon Apr 16 09:13:07 2012
rdoc-3.12 at Mon Apr 16 09:15:52 2012
json-1.6.6 at Mon Apr 16 09:30:55 2012
bundler-1.1.3 at Mon Apr 16 09:31:06 2012
```

Even though the bundler appears in the list, it does not seem to have been installed properly.

I hope someone can help me on this because I really need GitLabHQ to be working.

Daniela.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not a fix, really, but a workaround: Put this line:

```
gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

into a file named `~/.gemrc` to skip installation of rdoc and ri documentation (which you may not want on your system anyway - it will speed up the install process quite a bit).

Comment: Where do I need to put the file in case I install with root?

Comment: In the home directory - that's what `~` is short for. So `/root/.gemrc` in your case.

Comment: I added the .gemrc file to my project directory so it doesn't effect other projects.  This is only happening with ruby version 1.9.3-p194 for me.